# Get list of used values for some property

Tags: wikidata

Can I get list of used values for some property? For example, I would like to get a list of all used distinct values of P166 (award received) property.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: this is now a trivial operation thank to the Wikidata Query Service, to which you can send SPARQL requests:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?award WHERE {
  ?awarded_item wdt:P166 ?award .
}
```

- [try it in the GUI](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3Faward%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP166%20%3Faward%20.%0A%7D%0A)
- [get the results as JSON](https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?format=json&query=SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3Faward%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP166%20%3Faward%20.%0A%7D%0A)

**OUTDATED**:

A (brutal?) way to approach this would be to look for all the items that have this property, using the all-mighty [wmflabs WDQ tool](http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api_documentation.html):

`http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=claim[166]`

This returns 158 846 entity ids.
You could use those to build a first impression of what values this property takes, using the offical [Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php) (50 entities at a time maximum):

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&props=claims&format=json&ids=Q23|Q24|Q32|Q76|Q80|Q90|Q95|Q157|Q181|Q206|Q254|Q272|Q306|Q320|Q326|Q329|Q331|Q335|Q352|Q377|Q392|Q400|Q410|Q440|Q444|Q458|Q489|Q498|Q512|Q517|Q529|Q530|Q557|Q567|Q576|Q579|Q600|Q615|Q632|Q633|Q636|Q648|Q651|Q680|Q714|Q755|Q765|Q855|Q862|Q873|Q882
```

This would return a json with those entities' claims. You just have to do some (rather ugly) parsing (here in coffeescript, hope it's ok for you) to find what you are looking for:

```
properties = []
for entity, value of wikidataResponse.entities
  value.claims.P166.forEach (prop)->
    properties.push prop.mainsnak?.datavalue?.value?['numeric-id']
```

And (a little cleaning later) voila! The 122 values taken by the 50 first entities having the property P166:

```
[ 'Q17144', 'Q28003', 'Q31323', 'Q35637', 'Q37922', 'Q84020', 'Q93488', 'Q93716', 'Q93728', 'Q94121', 'Q103618', 'Q106301', 'Q120649', 'Q136733', 'Q145752', 'Q152337', 'Q154554', 'Q163700', 'Q178473', 'Q185493', 'Q208167', 'Q209896', 'Q218551', 'Q233454', 'Q278798', 'Q337463', 'Q465316', 'Q465774', 'Q541985', 'Q611968', 'Q680248', 'Q684511', 'Q697762', 'Q700899', 'Q721743', 'Q724443', 'Q758861', 'Q768999', 'Q805316', 'Q852071', 'Q858637', 'Q873842', 'Q896312', 'Q908745', 'Q908858', 'Q931502', 'Q963068', 'Q969644', 'Q976544', 'Q1059569', 'Q1063447', 'Q1081449', 'Q1123431', 'Q1139419', 'Q1141149', 'Q1316544', 'Q1357178', 'Q1364116', 'Q1415232', 'Q1442352', 'Q1465304', 'Q1543268', 'Q1599870', 'Q1789030', 'Q1818440', 'Q1818451', 'Q1853663', 'Q1969175', 'Q1991972', 'Q2325638', 'Q2329480', 'Q2465245', 'Q2536791', 'Q2547676', 'Q2727598', 'Q2990283', 'Q3295156', 'Q3324507', 'Q3403391', 'Q3405483', 'Q3519573', 'Q4273323', 'Q5593890', 'Q7241175', 'Q9052807', 'Q10855195', 'Q10855226', 'Q10855271', 'Q10905105', 'Q11599352', 'Q11609173', 'Q12177451', 'Q12201445', 'Q12201477', 'Q12270554', 'Q12981673', 'Q13422143', 'Q13452531', 'Q13554470', 'Q14539974', 'Q14539990', 'Q15117228', 'Q15229170', 'Q15278116', 'Q15631401', 'Q15710140', 'Q15831432', 'Q16141095', 'Q17099726', 'Q17200714', 'Q17355204', 'Q17373936' ]
```

That's already a good sample, but there is an import bias: the entities sample taken here being among the very first ones added to Wikidata (from Q23 to Q882), you will probably have a rather historically old and Western-centric set of P166 possible values. You might want to repeat this sampling with other parts of the 158 846 entities set (if not all).

Comment: This probably need updating to use the new query service now

Answer (score 2):

You could download [a dump of Wikidata in RDF format](http://tools.wmflabs.org/wikidata-exports/rdf/) and search that for all triples where the predicate is P166.

Probably the simplest way is to get the simplified dump (wikidata-simple-statements.nt.gz). In there, the property P166 is represented as a predicate with the URI `http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P166c`.